# How to make get_template_part always check child theme first?

Tags: get-template-part

How can I force WP to always check the child theme folder first when running `get_template_part`?

Example: child theme loads `get_template_part('content', 'inventory')` in `single.php`. Because all child themes (and there are a lot) share the same common inventory template base, the file `content-inventory.php` is in the parent theme. So far so good.

I would like to add a small section to said inventory template that will be unique to each child theme. Adding `get_template_part('content', 'inventory-special')` into `content-inventory.php` will not check the child theme directory first.

Comment: To the two of you who down-voted my answer and did not comment as to why, thanks for nothing. How is someone suppose to improve themselves with negative criticism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does, by default. The `get_template_part()` function uses `locate_template()` which cascades through the template files in in order of specificity and stylesheetpath/templatepath.

So, if your Child Theme includes a `content-inventory.php`, then `get_template_part()` will include it; if not, then it will look for `content-inventory.php` in the parent Theme. If it doesn't find it, it will then look for `content.php` first in the child, then in the parent.

**EDIT:**

Taking a stab at understanding what you mean; please clarify if I'm misunderstanding...

You want to include a new template part file within a Parent-Theme template file called `content-inventory.php`, right?

The only way, AFAIK, that you can do that is to *copy `content-inventory.php` into your Child Theme*, and then add the new `get_template_part()` call where needed.

If a file named `content-inventory.php` is included in *both* the Parent *and* the Child Theme, then WordPress will *always* use the **Child Theme** version, if included using `get_template_part()`.

Comment: @Kaiser, @Chip Bennett: WP will obviously check the parent theme for `content-inventory.php`. The Codex and simple experience makes that clear. However if the file being sought (level 2) is in the parent theme folder, WP does not recheck the child theme for a `get_template_part` contained within the file being sought (a third-tier include). Has this worked differently for you?

Comment: I don't understand your question/problem. For any given template file name, WordPress *always checks the **Child** Theme first*. Can you explain what you mean by second- and third-tier files?

Answer (score 4):

[`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) does this per default.